# How to define several float groups in a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match a string such as :

```
 k-point    1 :    0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000     weight = 0.01562500
```

I wrote that regex :

```
kpt_patt = re.compile("^\s*k-point\s+(\d+) :\s+" +
                      "([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s+" +
                      "([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s+" +
                      "([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s+" +
                      "weight = (\d+\.\d+)")

line = " k-point    1 :    0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000     weight = 0.01562500"
m = kpt_patt.match(line)
print(m.groups())

In [1]: m.groups()
Out[1]: ('1', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.01562500')
```

It works but is there a better way to said that I want this group `([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s+` several times ? Or a better way to write the whole regex of course.

Comment: It depends if the number of groups is fixed or not, and what final result structure you want to obtain. You might as well just use that `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` regex with `re.findall`.

Comment: How about using a format string?

Comment: I have this ; `^\s*k-point\s+(\d+) :\s+(\d*\.{0,1}\d*\s)*.*`

Comment: I would like to check if pattern matches and second export with `findall`.

Comment: @tobias_k, what do you mean ?

Comment: @Thomas, your expression match only the first integer

Comment: @Ger: Have a look at [`re.findall` solution I mentioned](http://ideone.com/ulQED2). No idea if you need that, but just an alternative... The last item of the tuple is the `weight` value (if the order of the values is fixed).

Comment: `^\s*k-point\s+\d+ :\s+((\d*\.{0,1}\d*\s)*).*$` you were right;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string multiplication. I've added the `r` prefix to your regex strings.

```
float_rx = r"([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s+"

kpt_patt = re.compile(r"^\s*k-point\s+(\d+) :\s+" +
                      float_rx * 3 +
                      r"weight = (\d+\.\d+)")
```

Also, your regex will not match numbers like `.123` or `1`. You may or may not care about this. This is what I typically use to match a float: `r"(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)"`. It will match numbers of these forms: `1`, `1.`, `1.1`, and `.1`, without matching `.`.

Comment: About your last comment, I have to change `\d+` in `\d*` ?